# C# - Remove Duplicated Lines ( MySql) c

Tags: c#, mysql

im trying to write a automation program that scrape data from site and update it in database every few seconds..
and i ran into a problem,

This is my Code :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ips.Count; i++)
        {
            MySqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO proxiestb (ip,port) VALUES (@ip,@port)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", ips[i].InnerText);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@port", ports[i].InnerText);
            Console.WriteLine(ips[i].InnerText + ":" + ports[i].InnerText);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Its working but the problem is that i want to check for dulicate lines and remove it .. beacuse i want this for loop run agian and again every 2-3 minutes..
please help me to figure out what i need to add to my code in order to check for duplicates and then remove them before the loop run again , thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: actually two ways to control duplicate one is indexing to particular table on database and second one before insert check whether the data is available on your table by code.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent inserting duplicates you can blindly push every line to the DB and let it handle duplicates like this:

```
INSERT INTO proxiestb (ip,port) 
VALUES (@ip,@port)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM proxiestb WHERE ip = @ip AND port = @port)
```

You'll still need to clean up any duplicates you already had in production tables but the above should prevent new ones.

I don't know if it's appropriate for your table outside of this bit of code but a unique constraint may also be worth looking into.